# GNU Octave: How to find n maximum elements of a vector

Tags: octave, vectorization, max

I have vector in  Octave like this:

```
[ 4 5 1 2 3 6 ]
```

Is there any function that returns n maximum elements of that vector, in this case, the three biggest are 6, 5, and 4?

```
[6 5 4]
```

The Octave max function only returns one maximum element.  I want n maximum elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function for this.

Comment: yes it is so helpful but i need index of maximum elements too

Comment: @miremehr: The `sort` function returns the indices as the second return value.

Answer (score 5):

**In GNU Octave, get the biggest n elements of a vector:**

```
octave:2> X = [3 8 2 9 4]
octave:2> sort(X)

ans =
   2   3   4   8   9

octave:8> sort(X)(end-2:end)

ans =

   4   8   9
```

**Description**

What `sort(X)(end-2:end)` means is "sort the vector X, and give me the elements from 2 minus the end to the end, also known as the last 3 elements".

Comment: it's probably simpler to use the `sort (X, "descend")(1:n)`